# Firebase user displayName is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm running this code in my react app:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    modelInstance.addObserver(this);
    modelInstance.getSignInStatus().then((user)=>{
      this.setState({
        userName: user !== false ? user.displayName : "Sign in",
        logged_in: user !== false ? true : false

      });
    });
  }
```

And here is modelInstance.getSignInStatus():

```
  this.getSignInStatus = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
        if (user){
          resolve(user);
        }
        else {
          resolve(false);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

What happens is that `this.state.userName` is set to `null`, meaning that `user.displayName` is `null`. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

```
  state = {
    username: "",
    email: "",
    passwordOne: "",
    passwordTwo: "",
    error: null
  }; 

  onSubmit = event => {
    const {username, email, passwordOne} = this.state;
    const {history} = this.props;

    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      .then(authUser => {
        db.doCreateUser(authUser.uid, username, email).then(() => {
          //you should clear your state fields here, for username / email etc
          console.log(authUser);
          //redirect user
          history.push(routes.HOME);
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({error});
      });
    event.preventDefault();
  };
```

`const auth = firebase.auth();`

`const db = firebase.database();` 
in order to acess doCreateUser

```
const doCreateUser = (id, username, email) =>
  db.ref(`users/${id}`).set({
    uid:id,
    username,
    email,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use setState for checking the auth status like so:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
    if (user){
      this.setState({user});
    }
}
```

Then you want the state of the displayName of the current user

```
componentDidMount() {
 modelInstance.addObserver(this);
 modelInstance.getSignInStatus().then((user)=>{
   this.setState({
     userName: this.state.user ? this.state.user.displayName : "Sign in",
     logged_in: this.state.user ? true : false
   });
 });
}
```

Obviously there has to be a name in the displayName property, If not you would have to update it. Let me know how this turns out.